# How to write a parameterized query in case statement with a REGEXP_LIKE and LIKE operator

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters

I'm trying to write a parameterized query in a case statement but I'm not entirely sure of the syntax. Something like this:

```
SELECT column1
FROM TABLE1
WHERE
CASE %(parameter)s
    WHEN '\|||()|[]|+' THEN REGEXP_LIKE (column1, %(parameter)s)
    WHEN '*|%|?|_' THEN LIKE '%(parameter)s'
    ELSE '*'
END
```

Essentially, I want the query to change based on what the user inputs.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is quite unclear what you want to do -- even with your edit.  `parameter` appears to be a column in a table, and a parameter passed into the query, and a confusing name whatever it is.

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is called a `WHERE` clause. It *filters* data, not the selected column list itself.

So: move it to `WHERE` and start from *there* (a poet in disguise, eh?).

Comment: Edited my question. Hopefully this is a little clearer on what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

REGEXP_LIKE returns boolean (true,false). It must be in the where clause or between when and then. The following is valid syntax.

```
SELECT parameter,
CASE      
      WHEN  parameter like '%' then 'Do Something'
      WHEN  parameter like '%Other' then 'Do something else' 
      ELSE 
           '*'
END FROM TABLE1
     WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (parameter, '^.*')
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've edited my question. I need to have the REGEXP_LIKE in the CASE statement